Error "virtual host to handle /favicon.ico has not been defined" When Deploying React App on IBM WebSphere
I am trying to deploy a React application on IBM WebSphere, but I am encountering an issue where the server returns the following error:
virtual host to handle /favicon.ico has not been Defined
Here are the steps I followed:

Built the React application using npm run build --prod.

Created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse.

Copied the contents of the build directory to the Eclipse project under webapp folder, ensuring the following structure:


ReactAppDeployment/
├── src/
│   ├── main/
│   │   ├── java/
│   │   ├── webapp/
│   │   │   ├── WEB-INF/
│   │   │   │   ├── web.xml
│   │   │   ├── static/
│   │   │   ├── index.html
│   │   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   │   ├── other files from build directory...



Exported the project as a WAR file.

Deployed the WAR file to WebSphere using the Integrated Solutions Console.

Configured the virtual host mappings in the console.


Here is the web.xml file I am using:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee                        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>My React App</display-name>
    <!-- Welcome file configuration -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- Default servlet to handle static files -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name> <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Despite this, I am still receiving the virtual host error for /favicon.ico.
What I've Tried:
Ensuring that the favicon.ico file is present in the build directory.
Mapping the application correctly to the default_host virtual host in the WebSphere console.
Verifying that host aliases for the virtual host are correctly configured.
What could be causing this virtual host error, and how can I resolve it?
Are there any specific settings in web.xml or WebSphere that I might be missing?

Browser will lookup favicon.ico  in website root. Not in some web application (war). put favicon.ico in your http server html root.

I checked its already present in context root.

Firefox , Tools > Web Developer > Web Developer Tools , click tab network, URL open your webapp, find favicon.ico URL

Message about favicon can be safely ingnored. it doesnt affect your application nor server in any way. To remove it you would have to map your application to root context - / - or deploy other application on that root context with just a favicon file. If you are using http server before your WAS, you can put it in the htdocs there also.
